# About Composition diamond lemma

Tags: lie-algebras, leibniz-algebras

Composition Diamond lemma for Lie algebra over a field $F$ has already been investigated in several papers :

> L.Bokut and Y.Q.Chen Groebner-Shirshov bases for Lie algebras

and

> A.I Shirshov, Some algorithmic problems for Lie algebras

I am looking for a paper including composition lemma for the case of Leibniz algebras? I appreciate your comments and your time in advance.

Comment: Even if it isn't specifically applicable , I recommend George Bergman's article on Newman's Diamond Lemma.  His presentation shows the wide generality of the Lemma.  Gerhard "Other Perspectives Can Be Useful" Paseman, 2016.07.24.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment,  the exact name of article is "on Newman's Diamond Lemma" ?

Comment: @user118746, I think that it is "[The diamond lemma for ring theory](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90010-5)" ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=506890)).